# Error 1603 when Installing Microsoft Intellitype Pro on Windows 7 x64

Tags: drivers, intellimouse

I just got a Microsoft Comfort Desktop 5000 and I'm trying to install Microsoft Intellitype 8.2 
But I always get the following error:

"*Setup must close because an error occurred. Verify that your computer meets the system requirements on the product packaging. Restart your computer and try running Setup again. If this error happens again, see Help for customer support options. (Error Code 1603)*"

By turning on Windows Installer logging and re-running the installer, I got a log file with this error message:

"*DIFXAPP: ERROR - The operating system you are running on is not supported. Only Windows 2000, Windows XP, Windows Server 2003 and Windows codenamed Longhorn are supported.*"

I'm running Windows 7 x64 with SP1 and all the latest updates (as of 9/9/2011).

I searched the Internet for 3 days now, and tried every solution suggested in Microsoft forums including doing a clean boot, and all in [this list](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953691) except uninstalling Windows Installer and re-installing it.

Please help. Any suggestions other than re-installing Windows are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the setup in Windows XP compatibility mode. You can do this by right clicking on the setup and changing the compatibility to "Windows XP SP3".

If that does not work, then you can try to download Driverpack Solution from http://drp.su/ which contains a lot of drivers and does the setup automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't try out this solution since I've re-installed Windows to fix some other problem and my problem was fixed. Thanks for your help anyway.